# Tengo un error al crear/generar reporte JasperReport - Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estoy realizando un sistema en NetBeans con Java y utilizo MySQL para la base de datos, me funciona todo lo que cargo al sistema pero cuando voy a consultas y genero el reporte (dependiendo de la consulta) me da error, el mismo lo realizo con JasperReport, El código para mostrar el reporte esta bien (por lo que hice) pero me da error de JasperReport.

Código donde genero el reporte. El mismo es sobre Facturas compras, se hace la búsqueda/consulta por Fecha o por proveedores y después se genera el reporte

```
public void report(){
   lista = new ArrayList();
    for (a = 0; a < tCompras.getRowCount(); a++) {

     Compras c = new Compras(tCompras.getValueAt(a, 1).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 4).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 5).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 7).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 8).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 9).toString(), tCompras.getValueAt(a, 10).toString());
        
     lista.add(c);
    }
    try{
    Reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/src/Formulario/Facturas_Compras.jasper"));
    parametro = new HashMap(2);
    parametro.put("Mes",mesCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
    parametro.put("Año",año.getText());
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Reporte, parametro,  new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print);
    view.setVisible(true);
    }catch(JRException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage()); 
    }  
}
```

Error que me arroja al generar el reporte

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.openStream()" because "url" is null
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:208)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
at Formulario.ConsultasCompras.report(ConsultasCompras.java:180)
at Formulario.ConsultasCompras.btngenerarActionPerformed(ConsultasCompras.java:487)
at Formulario.ConsultasCompras$8.actionPerformed(ConsultasCompras.java:359)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Que puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo me pasa en Ventas

Les dejos el proyecto en NetBeans con la  Base de Datos y Libreías si desean/quieren ver

PROYECTO + BASE DE DATOS
[Proyecto + Base de Datos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gx4Fs4CSFkH9x4RhVHVtIc3v88NHQK-o/view?usp=sharing)

LIBRERIAS
[Librerías](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P77IGOm1CzTuxfSozc7SQ9AOmaMjDRB1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Prueba quitando `/src` de la ruta. Y verifica que en Project Properties > Sources > Includes/Excludes el archivo .jasper se encuentre en Included Files.

Comment: OK modificare eso de `/src` y verificare lo de jasper.

Answer (score 1):

Cito:  `getClass().getResource` carga recursos desde la ruta de clases, no desde una ruta del sistema de archivos.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource

Comment: Lo que hago es tome de la clase compras variables o datos de la base de datos (nombres de los campos de la tabla)